# Passing array of strings from .c file to java dll via JNI

Tags: c#, java, c, interop, java-native-interface

I trying to get C# to instanciate a class in my java program. I have had a number of simpler examples working but I've hit the problem that my java class takes a string array as the constructor.

My question is how in a .c file do you create an string array that can then be passed through to the java class?

At the minute I've managed to pass across a single jString object.

Heres the method in my .c file.

```
jobject newClassInstance()
{

    jmethodID MID_init;
    jobject obj;
    jstring name;
    jobjectArray ret;

    MID_init = (*env)->GetMethodID (env, jClass, "<init>", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    if (!MID_init) {
        printf("Error: dllClass.<init>() not found\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    name = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"Moo");




    obj = (*env)->NewObject(env, jClass, MID_init, name);
    if (!obj) {
        printf("Error: failed to allocate an object\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Please let me know if you need anymore information.

Kind Regards

Ash

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- First create the array of strings.
- Create every Element String.
- Call Java Initializer with Array object.

Sample Code:

```
jobjectArray stringArray;
jString tmp;
char *stringA = "Test1";
char *stringB = "Test2";
jclass clsString; 
jint size = 2;

clsString = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/String");
stringArray = (*env)->NewObjectArray(env, size, clsString, 0);

tmp = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, stringB);
(*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env, stringArray, 0, tmp);

tmp = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, stringA);
(*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env, stringArray, 1, tmp);

obj = (*env)->NewObject(env, jClass, MID_init, stringArray);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I had managed to piece this together from various other websites but is good to have something to check it against :)

Comment: The whole of JNI is explained in "The Java™ Native
Interface Programmer’s Guide and Specification". You can download it under http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni. I got my whole knowledge of JNI from this.